# Non degenerate implies even dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a finite-dimensional non-zero purely odd super-vector space with non-degenerate super-symmetric pairing $(-,-)$, that is $(x,y)=-(y,x)\quad\forall x,y$.

How does this imply that this super-vector space is even dimensional?

Comment: Did you try doing the one dimensional case? What did you get?

Comment: If a basis is $\{x\}$, then $(x,x)=-(x,x)$, so $(x,x)=0$ and thus $(v,x)=0$ for all $v$, but $x\neq 0$, contradiction to non-degenerate.

Comment: Good work. Now try the two dimensional case. It will be interesting.

Comment: Well there is nothing to show if the dimension is 2. Did you mean the three dimensional case?

Comment: You are correct, technically. So try it next.

Comment: So if a basis is $(x,y,z)$,  we need to find $g\neq 0$ such that $(ax+by+cz,g)=0$ for all scalars $a,b,c$. Then there would be a contradiction to non-deg aswell. But I can't find such a $g$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80508/discussion-between-somos-and-ging).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odd-dimensional complex skew-symmetric matrix has eigenvalue $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165116/odd-dimensional-complex-skew-symmetric-matrix-has-eigenvalue-0)