# Why a skew-symmetric bilinear form is degenerate if the space is odd dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of odd dimension over a field F and $B:V\times V\rightarrow F$ an skew symmetric bilinear form. Why can we assert that $B$ is degenerate? Is it also true for any skew symmetric bilinear map $C: V\times V\rightarrow W$ where W is other vector space?

Comment: Hello, please be careful, this question already exists on this website. See for exemple [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165116/odd-dimensional-complex-skew-symmetric-matrix-has-eigenvalue-0)

Comment: @NaNoS That is obviously a related question, but not the same question. If you'd like to explain the connection between bilinear forms and the eigenvalues of their associated matrices as it pertains to this question, that would be a suitable answer

Comment: @BenGrossmann You're right Ben, I will try to write an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Since $B$ is skew symmetric then the adjoint of $B$ is $B^*=-B$, but $\det(B^*)=\det(B)$ so, since $\dim_F V$ is odd, we have $\det(B)=0$ (this works only if ${\rm car}(F)\neq 2$) therefore $B$ is degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

**For your first question** : first of all, you have to assume $\operatorname{car}(F) \neq 2$ as **Tuvasbien** mentioned. In fact, take $F = V = \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ so that $\dim_F(V) = 1$ and define $B(x,y) = xy$. Because $1 = -1$ in $F$, $B$ is a skew symmetric bilinear form but $B(1,1) = 1$ so that it is non-degenerate.

Now let $\operatorname{car}(F) \neq 2$, $n = \dim(V)$ and $\{e_1, \dotsc, e_n\}$ be a base of $V$. You have an isomorphism between the space of skew symmetric bilinear forms and the space of skew symmetric matrices by sending $B$ to its Gram matrix $G(B) := \left[B(e_i,e_j)\right]_{i,j}$. Under this identification, if $u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i e_i$ and $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$, then
$$B(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \dotsc & v_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}B(e_1, e_1) & B(e_1,e_2) & \dotsc & B(e_1, e_n) \\
B(e_2,e_1) & B(e_2,e_2) & \dotsc & B(e_2,e_n) \\
\vdots & \dotsc & \dotsc & \vdots \\
B(e_n, e_1) & B(e_n, e_2) & \dotsc & B(e_n, e_n) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w_1 \\ w_2 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \end{pmatrix}$$

It is well-known that $\det\left( G(B) \right) = \det\left( G(B)^T \right)$, but using the fact that $G(B)$ is skew symmetric, you get
$$\det\left(G(B)\right) = (-1)^n \det\left( G(B) \right) = -\det\left(G(B)\right)$$
as $n$ is odd, and because $\operatorname{car}(F) \neq 2$, you obtain $\det\left(G(B)\right) = 0$. It means that the matrix has a non-empty kernel, take $w \in F^n \backslash \{0\}$ such that $G(B)w = 0$. Seeing $w$ as a vector of $V$ under the isomorphism $V \simeq F^n$ given by the base $\{e_1, \dotsc, e_n\}$, for every $v \in V$, you have $B(v,w) = v^T G(B) w = v^T 0 = 0$ and it shows that $B$ is degenerate.

**For you second question** : I have to think about it. You can see a bilinear form $C : V \times V \to W$ as an element of $\mathcal{M}_{m, n^2}(F)$ whith $m = \dim(W)$ using tensor products but then the arguments above don't work anymore.